Call functions from Aptos Explorer | Aptos MOVE
I wrote some unit tests for my modules, which worked well. But I don't get why I can't call these functions on Aptos Explorer

The error is showed in the image is
Error: {"message":"parse arguments[1] failed, expect string<hex>, caused by error: invalid type: null, expected a string","error_code":"invalid_input","vm_error_code":null}

0 is a valid vector, isn't it?
Does anyone know about this problem?
Thank you so much!

I realize that I can pass the hex string format of the vector, and the Aptos Explorer accepts it. But I still wonder why the 0 doesn't work, because according to the How to use section of the Aptos Explorer, they said Vector arguments can be provided in JSON or as a comma separated list e.g. 0x1, 0x2 or ["0x1", "0x2"]

I'm still struggle with the vector, now my function requires vector<vector<u8>>, but Aptos Explorer doesn't accept the value [0x01, 0x02] or 0x01, 0x02?
